# How do I convert rows to column by using groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
   SHIP_ID        LON            LAT        LABEL_ETA     VESSEL_TYPE       TIMESTAMP_UTC_MONTH
0   23445      233.226313      0.363567      21858.0     CONTAINER SHIP            APR
1   32323      100.200100     -0.457523      21857.0     CONTAINER SHIP            JAN
2   55421      191.223145     -0.398676      21855.0     CONTAINER SHIP            FEB
3   45672      112.234589      0.438764      21852.0     CONTAINER SHIP            DEC
```

However, I want to make it in this way

```
   SHIP_ID       VESSEL_TYPE        JAN       FEB      MAR     APR .....    DEC
0   23445      CONTAINER SHIP      102.22    102.22    ...        
1   32323      CONTAINER SHIP      102.22    102.22    ...  
2   55421      CONTAINER SHIP      102.22    ..        ...
3   45672      CONTAINER SHIP      102.22    ..        ...
```

I'd like the TIMESTAMP_UTC_MONTH's data as the column which are the months and it contains the mean value of each month's LABEL_ETA.

LON AND LAT are to be excluded as well. I've tried methods like pivot_table() and it worked! But the requirement says I am only able to do it with groupby() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby(['SHIP_ID', 'VESEEL_TYPE', 'TIMESTAMP_UTC_MONTH']).LABEL_ETA.mean().unstack().reset_index()
```

Read more about grouping in [pandas' userguide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time in helping me out! however i am having issue with this code. it shows me an error message "'function' object has no attribute 'unstack'"

Comment: my bad, `.mean()` needs to be followed by parenthesis, try it now

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to have "the mean value of each month's LABEL_ETA", you can simply use:

```
df.groupby('TIMESTAMP_UTC_MONTH').LABEL_ETA.mean()
```

Comment: Thank you 
much appreciated!